# In MSAL.NET on the server, is there a way to supply a domain hint for single sign-on?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Searching the web, I see that if a site is using MSAL.**js**, the site developer can supply domain hints so that when a user begins to sign on, they aren't prompted with "Pick an account" on Microsoft's login site, and instead the library chooses the account for them, enabling a better single sign-on experience.  **Is there any way to supply a domain hint (or otherwise avoid the need for the "pick an account" prompt) when using MSAL.NET in a C# application**?

I am using MSAL.NET to authenticate against Azure AD via Open ID Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.  In `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)`, add an event handler for OnRedirectToIdentityProvider.

```cs
var events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
{
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = "mydomain.com";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
}
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme,
    options =>
    {
        // ...
        options.Events = events;
    }
);
```

Comment: AzureADDefaults is now obsolete. Looking for a new way to do this, if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WithExtraQueryParametersparameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.abstractapplicationbuilder-1.withextraqueryparameters?view=azure-dotnet) to pass **login_hint** and **domain_hint**

```
 IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appConfiguration.ClientId)
                                                    .WithAuthority(authority)
                                                    .WithRedirectUri(appConfiguration.RedirectUri)
                                                    .WithExtraQueryParameters("login_hint=myusername@mydomain.com")
                                                    .Build();
```

Comment: I don't have this builder anywhere.  In my ASP.NET app, I have `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` and later I call `builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(...).`, nothing like the above.  Do you have any more context on how I could use this?