# CS0618 'SignOutSessionStateManager' is obsolete: 'Use 'NavigateToLogout' instead. when upgrading Blazor WebAssembly from .NET 6 to .NET 7

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

Upgrading Blazor WebAssembly with individual user accounts I got the error below:

> Error (active)    CS0618  'SignOutSessionStateManager' is obsolete: 'Use
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Webassembly.Authentication.NavigationManagerExtensions.NavigateToLogout'
> instead.

How should `NavigateToLogout` be used?

Current code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a href="authentication/profile">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginSignOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/register">Register</a>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    private async Task BeginSignOut(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
        Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/logout");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a new Blazor WebAssembly project with individual user accounts and looking at `LoginDisplay.razor` it should be used like this `Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout");`.

Complete code example:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a href="authentication/profile">Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!</a>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginLogOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/register">Register</a>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    private void BeginLogOut()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I supply a domain_hint?  I used to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604911/in-msal-net-on-the-server-is-there-a-way-to-supply-a-domain-hint-for-single-sig

Comment: What about replacing `await aSignOutSessionStateManager.ValidateSignOutState()`, which will return true if signed out?